# Formatting numbers - grouping of decimal-place digits in Java

Tags: java, number-formatting, decimalformat

Does [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class support grouping of decimal-place digits similar to it does for integer part of numbers through methods `setGroupingUsed()` and `setGroupingSize`?

I'd like number 123456.789012 to be formatted as `123,456.789,012`.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I've not heard of this being done. Is this standard numeric formatting for any particular country? If so, have you tried using that country's Locale?

Comment: I have never see a format like that.

Comment: a more common format would be 123,456.789012

Comment: Interestingly, the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping) article has this to say: " In some countries, these 'digit group separators' are only employed to the left of the decimal separator; in others, they are also used to separate numbers with a long fractional part." What the article fails to mention, however, is **which** countries use each style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [API guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

> The grouping separator is commonly used for thousands, but in some
> countries it separates ten-thousands. The grouping size is a constant
> number of digits between the grouping characters, such as 3 for
> 100,000,000 or 4 for 1,0000,0000. If you supply a pattern with
> multiple grouping characters, the interval between the last one and
> the end of the integer is the one that is used. So "#,##,###,####" ==
> "######,####" == "##,####,####".

This passage suggests that the grouping symbol can only be applied to the integer portion of the number. If we set a pattern like so:

```
String pattern = "###,###.###,###";
```

and pass it to an instance of `DecimalFormat`, the result is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed pattern "###,###.###,###"
```

whereas the more typical:

```
String pattern = "###,###.###";
```

works as expected.

`setGroupingUsed` isn't applicable because it takes a boolean to indicate whether the number will be expressed with grouped digits. `setGroupingSize` isn't applicable either, because it only governs how many digits comprise each group.

The only way to get what you want is to roll your own formatter.

Addendum:

Cracking open the [source](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/text/DecimalFormat.java) of `DecimalFormat` reveals that the number to be formatted is divided into three sections: `leftDigits`, or the leftmost digits of the integer portion of the number, `zeroDigits`, or the rightmost digits of the integer portion of the number, and `rightDigits`, or the fractional portion of the number.

The code includes the following (comment starts at line 2507):

```
// The position of the last grouping character is
// recorded (should be somewhere within the first two blocks
// of characters)
```

By "blocks," the comment clearly refers to `leftDigits` and `zeroDigits`, so even the developers assumed that grouping digits would only occur in the integer portion and made no provisions for grouping on the fractional portion (aside from throwing an exception).

Comment: This is really disappointing.  For me, having commas every 3 digits on the right hand side of the decimal looks normal.  I would have expected DecimalFormat to do this out of the box.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Out of curiosity, are you familiar with which countries or professions use grouped digits on the fractional portion of a number? I couldn't find anything online other than mathematicians who group with thin spaces every five digits. The ISO standard seems to be dot or comma to indicate decimal and thin spaces for grouping, but it makes no mention of grouping in the fractional portion.

Comment: Nicely presented!

Comment: No, I'm really not.  Actually, I'm awfully surprised by the three comments under the question - two where the commentator denies having seen/heard this, and one saying it's less common than omitting the commas.

Answer (score 0):

There is no grouping after the decimal place. Such a format will be invalid and throw an exception.

Comment: What code would throw an exception and what exception?

Comment: The comma after decimal place